# Ionic2 - Change location of iOS date picker on screen

Tags: ios, css, sass, ionic2

I am new to Ionic 2 so forgive me if this is a silly css question. How can I change the location of the iOS date picker on the screen? It defaults to the bottom of the screen, but I would like to vertically center it.

I noticed that, in the DOM, the date picker has a class of datepicker-wrapper, which has a transform: translateY(0%) property, but I haven't been able to figure out how to manipulate this.

Answer (score 0):

You can override this class:

```
.picker-wrapper {
    transform: translateY(-50%)!important;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get that to work. I can't get the .picker-wrapper css to update programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first answer did not have the class name correct.

```
.datepicker-wrapper {
    transform: translateY(-50%)!important;
}
```